# Having trouble with a script to find the date and time in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, I have a script to log the date and time in a text file:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set datetime=%%G
set year=%datetime:~0,4%
rem pause
set month=%datetime:~4,2%
set day=%datetime:~6,2%
set /a day2=day+5
echo %year%/%month%/%day2%> C:\WLT\Init\lastoptim.txt
```

And a similar one in a script that runs on startup:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%G in ('type C:\WLT\Init\lastoptim.txt') do set datetime2=%%G
set year=2%datetime2:~0,4%
rem pause
set month2=%datetime2:~4,2%
set day2=%datetime2:~6,2%
set /a day3=day2+1
echo %year2%/%month2%/%day3%> lastoptim2.txt
echo %year2%/%month2%/%day3%
```

But it doesn’t work. What I need is a script to extract a date from %date% into a text file, and then another one to take that date, see if the current date is X number of days later, and if it is, then run a command.
Would like this script to be entirely dependent on cmd, because this is going to be used on systems as far back as XP. Using an external app (e.g. an exe that prints out the date in a specific format) would be fine.

Comment: There are better ways to solve that problem. For instance, rather than writing the date to the file, you can just update the file's timestamp and then, check if the timestamp has recently changed. Also, the choice of language may help. For instance, even though you tagged this as a batch-file question. There's nothing stopping us from running vbscript (via cscript.exe) or powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Your question still not clear for me, but if you want to add one day or one month for your dates, here is an example :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Manipulate DATES WITH BATCH
@for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /value') do for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%a") do set "%%#"
:: Store the local date inside a variable
set "CurrentDateTime=%LocalDateTime%"
set "CurrentDate=%CurrentDateTime:~0,4%/%CurrentDateTime:~4,2%/%CurrentDateTime:~6,2%"
:: Here Adding One day
@for /f %%a in ('Powershell -C "(Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')"') do set "NextDay=%%a"
:: Here adding 1 month
@for /f %%a in ('Powershell -C "(Get-Date).AddMonths(1).ToString('yyyy/MM/dd')"') do set "NextMonth=%%a"
echo( CurrentDate : %CurrentDate%
echo( NextDay     : %NextDay%
echo( NextMonth   : %NextMonth%
pause
```